# Show the newly created record on .save()

Tags: ember.js

Ember 2.5

I have a page that displays a list of all types of commutes (/commutetypes). To create a new commute type, I go to commutetypes/new.

Once I save the new commute type and transition back to /commutetypes. The new commute type does not display on the list. Can I refresh the model to display it?

```
// save action in route.
save: function() {
    var _this = this;

    var com = this.store.createRecord('commutetype', {
        name: document.getElementById('nameInput').value,
        description: document.getElementById('descriptionInput').value
    });
    com.save().then(function(){
        _this.transitionTo('commutetypes');
    });
}
```

Added model for commutetypes route.

```
model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      commutetypes:  this.store.query('commutetype', params)
    });
},
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your commutetypes route as well? Might be something with your model hook.

Comment: How does your response of the createRecord-API call look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to pass in your model inside transitionTo. Also make sure that you endpoint returns a 201 with model instance

```
com.save().then(function(data){
  _this.transitionTo('commutetypes', data);
}
```

I would also need to make sure that from server side you get instance of model back to ember.

Can you post your route code commute types...maybe you are not loading data there properly

hope it helps

Comment: This works but I haven't tested it on a route with multiple models yet. Does this still fire the model hook?

Comment: No it will not since you are feeding a route with model.